# configure a database connection when using localhost

Tags: php, sql-server, localhost, http-error

I am trying to setup my local computer so that I can work on a web application. One of the php files I have calls to a SQL server table  to display information. I know it works because this is already an existing site on a web server, however when I try to launch it on my local computer I am getting an http error 500. I included

```
init_set("display_errors","1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and I am not getting any errors just and http 500 error. 
Am I supposed to configure my database to allow my localhost to retrieve information?
I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Add some error handling in your code. Also enable errors being sent to the browser in IIS so you can see the errors. Look in the iis logs for details. A 500 error is a generic error message on purpose to not provide details for hacking attempts. Without knowing what the actual error is this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Can you post your connection string for the app? And just because you're using SSMS, doesn't mean you have SQL Server installed on your local computer.

Comment: Hello @Boxwer19, First, you need to check that particular `php` file to validate which SQL Server it's pointing to.

Comment: not sure if this is what you need to see but I am using $dbh = new PDO ( 'dbName', '', '' ); like I said it works fine up on the web server so I don't think anything is wrong with the code itself, but I may be wrong

Comment: I just tried another webpage and same thing I am not getting the information from the server, but it loads up so no 500 error. However on this one I get this error Error! C:\Programs\zend\file\index.php (10) : SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: @Boxer19, the error says it, you may want validate your connection string ([for your ref..](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php))